# Apache how to server more apps from same domain based on path?

Tags: linux, apache, vhosts

I have a web app that is composed from 2 apps:
 - a simple PHP presentation site that handle account creation
 - an API ran by a Tomcat server
I have the apache setup to server at mydomain.com the PHP, but I want to server at mydomain.com/api the Java app that runs on 127.0.0.1:8080.

I know how to do this using api.mydomain.com, but I have single site SSL certificate that does not cover subdomains, this is why I need to do this by path.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are looking for a reverse proxy.
See: http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/protect-your-ports-reverse-proxy?page=0,0

Edit: I think below two links are closer to your use case
https://stackoverflow.com/a/1252993/115896
http://blog.lundscape.com/2009/05/configure-a-reverse-proxy-with-apache/